# How to set output using regular expression in a textarea

Tags: php, regex

Im going to use a regular expression that detect what we typed in a `textarea`.

For an example, Imagine you entered `-hello` in the `textarea` and clicked on Print button. How we can set it as a `<li>` item?

I used this pattern for Persian language, and it works well. as you can see in the image.

```
$ptrn_FA = '([^\n]*)\s*-';
```

[image]

But the pattern of bellow, dont work for English language.

```
$ptrn_EN = '[^\n]-\s*(\w\d*[^\n])';
```

[image]

The question is how to fix issue for English language? As the final image i want to get output like the image of bellow, As in the image you can see there might be multiply items in a `textarea` .

[image]

Comment: You're really just splitting on new lines, and trying to accept any characters...why don't you just explode it on `\n`?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, There might be multiply lines with a `-` or without it.so im trying to get each line(s) to detect which one is with a dash to print them in output.The last image in the post might be more clear.

Comment: So what you want to do is detect a new line OR a dash? `^([\n]|-)`?

Answer (score 0):

The first part of your regular expression

```
[^\n]-
```

is looking for two chars: NOT A NEW LINE and '-'. If you just have one char '-', the regular expression will not match.

Try this one:

```
$ptrn_EN = '[^\n]*-\s*([^\n]*)';
```

If you don't have to test for new lines, the next one will be more clear:

```
$ptrn_EN = '\s*-\s*(\w+)';
```